# Java AWS S3 PutObject MultiPart file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am facing some issue while trying to put an image file on S3,

```
 exception = "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException";
    message = "Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /home/ubuntu/image1517896928.png (No such file or directory)";
```

I am first downloading the MultipartFile on my server and then using the file I call the putObject method,
Because the S3 putObject method take following parameters -

```
putObject(String arg0, String arg1, File arg2)
```

**Here's my code -**

```
public String uploadImage(MultipartFile image) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    File localFile = new File(SERVER_HOME_DIRECTORY + image.getOriginalFilename());

    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client();
    s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "prefix", localFile));

    return "ok";      
}
```

Comment: Error message says what's wrong. `/home/ubuntu/image1517896928.png (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Yes I checked, Image is there on the location, I am deleting the image after the put, could it be the putObject is async? and by the time my code deletes the image from server, the file might not have been put on S3?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to propose using `TransferManager` which is very reliable and provide better performance for transferring the files to S3. It is the options to check the upload progress as well (using listener).

[TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

[Sample code using TransferManager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/)

> TransferManager provides a simple API for uploading content to Amazon
>   S3, and makes extensive use of Amazon S3 multipart uploads to achieve
>   enhanced throughput, performance and reliability.
>
> When possible, TransferManager attempts to use multiple threads to
>   upload multiple parts of a single upload at once. When dealing with
>   large content sizes and high bandwidth, this can have a significant
>   increase on throughput.

Comment: Just adding to this, the TransferManager is currently only available in AWS SDK V1, it is still in development for V2. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/docs/design/services/s3/transfermanager

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the multipart file to the localFile first. `image.transferTo(localFile);`

```
public String uploadImage(MultipartFile image) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    File localFile = new File(SERVER_HOME_DIRECTORY + image.getOriginalFilename());
    image.transferTo(localFile);
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client();
    s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "prefix", localFile));

    return "ok";      
}
```

Comment: what is class of multipart.transferTo method ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo%28java.io.File%29